# verilog 'always block' in 'for loop'

Tags: verilog

```
always@(negedge ena) begin

 for(k=0;k<16;k=k+1) begin
  

      //task
    
      //statement 1
    
      //statement 2
    
    
      //task
    
      //statement 3
    
      //statement 4
    
      //task
    
      //statement 5
    
      //statement 6
    
     end
    
    end
```

1. I know that the above code executes the statements inside the 'for' at the same time, is that
   correct?
2. I want the statements in the for to be executed sequentially like

   " task -> statement 1 -> statement 2 -> task  "

Comment: **all** statements *inside an always block* are executed *sequentially* according to a generic programming language rules, which include conditional statements and loops.

Answer (score 1):

Do not confuse *at the same time* with *concurrent execution* in simulation.

All statements within a `begin/end` block of code execute in sequential order. Each iteration of a procedural `for` loop executes in sequential order.

In this example they all statements execute *at the same time*, which is when the `negedge` of `ena` occurs, but they do execute in a sequential order.